# L'inversion dans la phrase affirmative

Tags: grammaire, verbes, inversion

Dans la phrase,

> Comme disent leurs mères, la famille, c'est sacré.

Pourquoi l'inversion est-elle utilisée dans cette phrase ?

Comment: @Toto : Je crois que l'OP parle de cette inversion: au lieu de "Comme leurs mères disent" c'est "Comme disent leurs mères".

Comment: Quick notes: (a) The carefully written version of this sentence would begin *Comme **le** disent*. (b) It's absolutely possible, but slightly less stylistically nice, to say *Comme leurs mères le disent*. (c) Some of [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25885/que-followed-by-verbs/25886#25886) (and the one linked within it) might be helpful. I'd have to think about this more before formulating an answer, though.

Comment: "le disent" makes for a better style, in my opinion, and is the dominating form : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comme+disent+leurs%2Ccomme+le+disent+leurs&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomme%20disent%20leurs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomme%20le%20disent%20leurs%3B%2Cc0 although for the past 70 years it's been used with a comparable frequency.

Comment: @dimitris: Tout-à-fait, mais la question a changé après mon commentaire qui, du coup, devient obsolète.

Answer (score 1):

L'inversion n'est pas utilisée que dans cette phrase, et selon le petit rectificatif avec lequel la question devrait être comprise, c'est à dire « ce schéma de phrase », elle est pratiquée généralement ; pour les formes verbales suivantes et la forme complète l'inversion pour les noms n'est pas faite qu'exceptionnellement ;

[disent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comme+nous+le+disent+*%2Ccomme+*+nous+le+disent&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomme%20nous%20le%20disent%20les%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomme%20ils%20nous%20le%20disent%3B%2Cc0),
[apprendre](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comme+nous+l%27apprend+*%2Ccomme+*+nous+l%27apprend&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ccomme%20nous%20l%27%20apprend%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20apprend%20l%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20apprend%20le%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20apprend%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20apprend%20une%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20apprend%20un%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20apprend%20M.%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20apprend%20saint%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20apprend%20encore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20apprend%20son%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20apprend%20Tacite%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Ccomme%20%2A%20nous%20l%27%20apprend%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcomme%20il%20nous%20l%27%20apprend%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20Pline%20nous%20l%27%20apprend%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20on%20nous%20l%27%20apprend%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20elle%20nous%20l%27%20apprend%3B%2Cc0), 
[montre](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comme+nous+le+montre+*%2Ccomme+*+nous+le+montre&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ccomme%20nous%20le%20montre%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20le%20montre%20le%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20le%20montre%20l%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20le%20montre%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20le%20montre%20une%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20le%20montre%20un%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20le%20montre%20M.%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20le%20montre%20l%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20le%20montre%20ce%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20le%20montre%20cette%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20le%20montre%20son%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Ccomme%20%2A%20nous%20le%20montre%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcomme%20il%20nous%20le%20montre%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20on%20nous%20le%20montre%3B%2Cc0),
[indique](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comme+nous+l%27indique+*%2Ccomme+*+nous+l%27indique&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ccomme%20nous%20l%27%20indique%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20indique%20le%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20indique%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20indique%20l%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20indique%20une%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20indique%20un%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20indique%20M.%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20indique%20ce%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20indique%20son%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Ccomme%20%2A%20nous%20l%27%20indique%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcomme%20il%20nous%20l%27%20indique%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20on%20nous%20l%27%20indique%3B%2Cc0),
[enseigne](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comme+nous+l%27enseigne+*%2Ccomme+*+nous+l%27enseigne&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ccomme%20nous%20l%27%20enseigne%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20enseigne%20l%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20enseigne%20le%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20enseigne%20saint%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20enseigne%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20enseigne%20notre%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20nous%20l%27%20enseigne%20une%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Ccomme%20%2A%20nous%20l%27%20enseigne%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcomme%20il%20nous%20l%27%20enseigne%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomme%20on%20nous%20l%27%20enseigne%3B%2Cc0)

Une possible explication de cette inversion serait l'idée d'un relativement trop grand éloignement du verbe dans la forme complète (avec le COD), celui-ci, rejeté à la fin, se trouvant séparé du sujet par le COI et le COD ; l'inversion rendrait au verbe une place centrale. Par habitude, elle aurait été faite par la suite lorsque la forme tronquée est utilisée. Il s'agit donc d'inversion stylistique. Je n'ai cependant pas de sources de support pour pouvoir considérer cela comme une explication définitive.

Answer (score 1):

L'inversion concerne ici la proposition subordonnée :

> comme **disent leurs mères**,...

alors qu'on s'attendait à :

> comme **leurs mères disent**,...

Le pronom relatif *comme* a ici une valeur métadiscursive, c'est à dire qu'il ne sert pas à introduire une comparaison, ce qui n'aurait pas de sens ici, mais annonce une proposition qui à trait au discours lui-même.

L'inversion n'est pas obligatoire, mais considérée comme plus élégante, de meilleur style. Elle est d'ailleurs tellement courante que nous sommes plusieurs à ne pas l'avoir détectée à la première lecture de la question.

Une recherche de Ngrams montre une très large domination de l'inversion dans ce type de subordonnées :

[image]

Cette utilisation de *comme* est ancienne, on la trouve par exemple chez Joachim du Bellay dans *La deffence, et illvstration de la langue francoyse*, 1549

> Sonne-moy ces beaux sonnets, non moins docte que plaisante invention italienne, conforme de nom à l'ode, et différente d'elle seulement pour ce que le sonnet a certains vers reiglez et limitez, et l'ode peut courir par toutes manières de vers librement, voyre en inventer à plaisir à l'exemple d'Horace, qui a chanté en XIX sortes de vers, comme **disent les grammairiens**.

Cette inversion peut être comparée à celle, obligatoire, que l'on rencontre dans les incises :

> La famille, c'est sacré, **disent leurs mères**.